# new FileInfo(path).Name versus Path.GetFileName(path)

Tags: c#, .net

which one is better to use and why?
I mean in which aspects these two commands differ and how?
Performance, readability, ...

`new FileInfo(path).Name` or `Path.GetFileName(path)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply as you won't have to Create a new Object for using Path.GetFilename() it will perform better.

Here is a Comparison for both:

Code:

```
Path.GetFileName("G:\\u.png")
```

IL:

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "G:\u.png"
IL_0005:  call        System.IO.Path.GetFileName
```

Code:

```
new FileInfo("G:\\u.png").Name
```

IL:

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "G:\u.png"
IL_0005:  newobj      System.IO.FileInfo..ctor
IL_000A:  callvirt    System.IO.FileSystemInfo.get_Name
```

Comment: You're correct in saying Path.GetFileName is faster, but it's wrong to think its *automatically* faster because it's static.  Who's to say it's not creating objects internally?

Comment: @joe Path only separates the string given. Nothing else. It is a convenience so that you do not have to do it yourself. It does not create any other objects, apart from the strings.

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest using Path.GetFilename() because it simply parses path and returns file name. On other hand `FileInfo` object will check if executed code has rights to access specified file which is relatively slow.

Comment: Also the overhead of creating a FileInfo object, so if this is happening in a loop on each iteration, it affects performance adversely

Answer (score 0):

Performancewise Path.GetFilename() will outperform the other version as it is static. Your first version creates an object which has to be instantiated and garbage collected.

Readability: Path.GetFilename() clearly wins IMHO!

The way they figure out the name won't differ much I think.

Comment: -1 It has nothing to do with static or not. The performance difference is due to the permission checks.

Comment: What are you going on about? Of course it makes a difference if an object has to be created or not. In case of "new FileInfo()" it HAS to be created. See Shekhar_Pro's answer to see the IL representation.
If FileInfo() does additional permission checks is a totally different story.

Comment: Path only does parsing. No streams are opened. No permissions checked, nothing like that.