# How can I just get the base filename from this C# code?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Notes", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach(string file in files)
```

When I check the contents of file it has the directory path and extension. Is there a way I can just get the filename out of that?

Comment: As an aside..  You probably shouldn't be calling these things file and files.  Those things generally refer to file descriptors on unix and file handles(??) on windows.  It would probably be (slightly) clearer to people perusing your code to call them filename and filenames respectively.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
string name = fi.Name;
```

If you want *just* the file name - quick and simple - use [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx):

```
string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
```

Comment: Becuase this is so overkill. My tests indicate that it is approximately 11 times slower than just `Path.GetFileName`. There are correct times to use both, but this is not the time to use `FileInfo`

Comment: Check this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979762/new-fileinfopath-name-versus-path-getfilenamepath

Comment: @Oskar: The OP never indicated performance requirements. Also, no one is sure what other information the OP will need for his application, like file attributes.

Comment: @Evan does that really matter? I don't think this is a good way to do it, thus the downvote

Comment: @Evan if he needs the fileinfo class in a foreach loop, it is faster to create a DirectoryInfo and use GetFiles if I recall correctly

Answer (score 20):

You can use the following method: `Path.GetFileName(file)`

Answer (score 4):

```
System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\pagefile.sys");  // Sample file.
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(f.FullName);  // With extension.
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FullName));  // What you wants.
```

Comment: Firstly, `FileInfo.FullName` will give you the *full* filepath which is not what the question asks. Secondly, if you are going to use `System.IO.Path` methods, why bother creating a `FileInfo` object in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to strip away the extension, path, etc. you should fill this string into a [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) and use its properties or use the static methods of the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) class.