# How can I get only part of a file path name?

Tags: c#

This is the line:

```
string t = Path.GetDirectoryName(file1);
```

The result is:

```
C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\AppData\\Local\\Extracting_Frames\\Extracting_Frames\\dat file\\converted.avi\\histogramValues.dat
```

I want it to only contain: `converted.avi`.

PS: `converted.avi` is not a file name it's a path name. I want to get the last part of the path the last subdirectory without the file name.

Comment: Is `converted.avi` folder name or file name?

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan my mistake I didn't explain that converted.avi is a directory name wich is a subdirectory. if this is file1: C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\AppData\\Local\\Extracting_Frames\\Extracting_Frames\\dat file\\converted.avi\\histogramValues.dat so I want to get the last subdirectory only without the file name. So t in the end will contain only: converted.avi wich is a directory not a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `converted.avi` is the file name then use this

```
string t = Path.GetFileName(file1);
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

However, if that is the name of a directory, you could just extract everything after the last backslash from the result you already have. eg

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
var parentFolder = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\')+1);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/RYPMI91227

Comment: No my mistake it's not what I wanted. file1 contain: C:\\Users\\bout0_000\\AppData\\Local\\Extracting_Frames\\Extracting_Frames\\dat file\\converted.avi\\histogramValues.dat I want to get only the part of the path wich is: converted.avi

Comment: converted.avi is not a file name it's a path name. I want to get the last part of the path the last subdirectory without the file name.

Comment: @Jhonatan Birdy - then FileInfo might help

Comment: No need to use SubString and LastIndexOf. Just use Path.GetFileName(path)

Comment: @parvus  - did you actually *read* this answer, or the question for that matter?

Comment: @Jamiec Well... yes! I actually feel a bit stupid now that even after your reprimand I still don't see what's wrong with my remark. I forked your rextester: http://rextester.com/ETFH60769

Comment: @parvus - My point was that I actually pointed out the use of `Path.GetFileName()`. Your point is somewhat valid, that the same method gets the first thing inside a path that vaguely looks like a file name. So it works - but kind of by luck not judgement. IMO, that method should be retrieving `histogramValues.dat` from the example given.

Answer (score 0):

You want FileInfo.Name:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name(v=vs.80).aspx

so something like:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file1);
var fileName = fileInfo.Name; // this will only contain converted.avi
```

Comment: This is not a good idea to use _FileInfo_ because it requires read permission on the specified file. (look at the exceptions thrown by [_FileInfo_ constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx))

Comment: @CédricBignon, absolutely, OP hasn't said if that's a problem yet, a good overview of the two methods described in the various answers in this thread are also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979762/new-fileinfopath-name-versus-path-getfilenamepath  ...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Path.GetFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) will return the file name

Answer (score 0):

Use File Info

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(yourFilePath);
var filename = info.Name;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This is not a good idea to use _FileInfo_ because it requires read permission on the specified file. (look at the exceptions thrown by [_FileInfo_ constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetFileName() function of the Path class