# Regular expression for getting filenames from img tag of html code

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to retrieve filenames of the images (`img` tag) from a string containing html code.

Example below: a string (html code) containing 2 `img` html tags. Need to get filenames (not full url) of the images.

```
<p>One two thre four</p>

<img src="http://localhost:5000/uploads/360e2b55a984178fd102a6cff9d70bc943936461.jpg" 
style="width: 300px; display: block; vertical-align: top; margin: 5px auto; 
text-align: center;">

<p>Five six seven</p>

<img src="http://localhost:5000/uploads/a77381fa354a067ed128bc8fe5cdfc8f85aaedea.jpg" 
style="width: 300px; display: block; vertical-align: top; margin: 5px auto; 
text-align: center;">

<p>Eight nine ten</p>
```

Maybe this is feasable with a regular expression but I'm not an expert.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use a html parser.

Comment: Why is this marked as c# please clarify why that is the case here.  Without that indication i.e. with JavaScript this would be a simple task to retrieve the `src` attribute here.

Comment: This is marked as C# because I need to code this stuff with C#. Needed to clarify sorry.

Comment: I provided a somewhat generic answer here given it is not clear how this HTML is obtained or contained which may play into a better answer.

Comment: Note, this HTML for the `img` element as you have it also appears to be invalid as "An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions." - be sure you meet those condition. There is a link regarding that in the explanation here in the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/img.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this question to get the src [Regular Expression to get the SRC of images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4257359/125981)
THEN use this one for the base name [new FileInfo(path).Name versus Path.GetFileName(path)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4979762/125981)

SO it is "kind of a duplicate" but combination of both questions code to accomplish what you want.  Generally, it s not the best idea to use regex to parse HTML, so many things in the way HTML can constructed and then be placed on a page, be sure to test all your definitions.

Comment: Here is a list of all the attributes that you might test against, in any order within the element definition.  https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/img.html

Comment: You point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex I recommend html agility pack https://html-agility-pack.net/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following regex that capture file name with extension of image element

```
<img\s+.*?src=['\"]?.*\/(.*?\..{3,4})['\"]?
```

also you can check its matches in the following [link](https://regex101.com/r/SuHW6C/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern: `([^\/]+jpg)`

You can check: [link](https://regex101.com/r/fE9nRr/1)